# Get Amazon Resource Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to list the Amazon Resource Name ([ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)) of an S3 Bucket from the web GUI?

I know I can piece it together myself, but that just seems unnecessary. Ideally, I could go to the S3 instance page and copy and paste the ARN. I've looked in the properties page of the bucket, but I'm not seeing anything that looks useful there.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Tagging.ARN.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the current S3 console does not expose bucket ARNs. You could probably add a feature to the S3 console page to yield ARNs with a simple GreaseMonkey script.

Comment: Console page is another name for the web GUI?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The AWS console is the web gui at http://console.aws.amazon.com/. I'm calling each of the service-specific web guis an individual web console within the overarching AWS console, for example the S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home, the DynamoDB console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home etc.

Comment: Gotchya. Thanks for the info!